# Javascript - Replacing all strings inside object

Tags: javascript, object

```
var obj = {r: {e: {c: {u: {r: "sion", string: "abc"}}}}};
```

How can I reverse all strings in this object? So that I get an object like this:

```
{r: {e: {c: {u: {r: "nois", string: "cba"}}}}}
```

(I could not find any similar question)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and look for objects or strings.

```js
const reverseStrings = object => {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') reverseStrings(v);
        else if (typeof v === 'string') object[k] = Array.from(v).reverse().join('');
    });
}

var object = { r: { e: { c: { u: { r: "sion", string: "abc" } } } } };

reverseStrings(object);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: This was what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You write a recursive loop that iterates over all the the object values and then `split`, `reverse`, `join` the value if the value is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a recursive function that will go through the object entries of the current object and use `.reduce` to put it back to `object` :

```js
const obj = { r: { e: { c: { u: { r: "sion", string: "abc" } } } } };

const reverseStrings = obj => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if(typeof v === "object"){
      acc[k] = reverseStrings(v);
    }
    else{
      acc[k] = [...v].reverse().join('');
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const result = reverseStrings(obj);

console.log(result)
```